# Evitar la superposición de imágenes en mi web al hacer lazyload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagen

Tenemos una página web en la que las imágenes (están organizadas en filas/columnas) tienen la propiedad responsive.

Lo que tengo que hacer es poner/introducir el efecto LazyLoad (cosa que si que me funciona), pero al hacerlo y cargarse las imagenes secuencialmente, las imágenes se me superponen las de arriba con las de abajo. Así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo curioso es que al mover la ventana del navegador se quedan como tienen que quedar. Así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puedo hacer para que al cargar la pagina, mientras se van cargando las imágenes ya se queden de la forma correcta?

Tengo un div, dentro de este div tengo un enlace (para al pulsar encima de la imagen), y dentro del enlace es donde tengo la imagen.
Así:

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 port-item 1a12">
<a href="OlafurEliasson_Sligthly.html" style="display:block; position:relative">
<img class="lazyload" data-original="../images/obras/OlafurEliasson_Sligthly.jpg" alt="obras">
</a>
</div>
```

Si en vez de "data-original" pongo "src" si que se quedan las imágenes ok pero no hace el efecto lazyload.

Código JQuery:

```
<script src="../js/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/lazysizes.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        $("img.lazyload").lazyload({
            effect : "fadeIn"
        }); 
    });
</script>

<script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Sii. Todos los elementos son iguales (la class=col-lg-2...). Eso es del plugin de bootstrap que yo ni he implementado ni tocado ni se como funciona (ya estaba hecho). Como lo he mostrado en la pregunta es el orden correcto, excepto la linea https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> que en mi proyecto la tengo en el head. Todo lo otro de jquery lo tengo antes de cerrar la etiqueta .

Comment: Añade el código de jQuery para ver como estas haciendo la llamada a Ajax y como añades las imágenes al dom.

Comment: No sé como funciona ese plugin pero puedes poner a las imágenes alto y ancho en el HTML para que mantengan el tamaño aunque no se hayan cargado, por ejemplo: `<img class="lazyload" data-original="../images/obras/OlafurEliasson_Sligthly.jpg" alt="obras" width="300px" height="400px">`

Comment: La solución de @blonfu es la ideal, pero si quieres que te corrijamos el efecto LazyLoad que estás creando deberías compartir el código o bien darnos el enlace a la descarga.

Comment: Pongo el código JQuery. Pero claro, si que probé a poner las medidas de la imagen (width y heigh), pero al hacer eso ya no funcionan las imagenes con el responsive (adecuarse a la pantalla/navegador)

Comment: Estoy tratando de reproducir tu problema y no consigo que me ocurra lo que a ti. ¿Todos los elementos son iguales (`class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 port-item 1a12"`)?

Comment: Por tu código supongo que usas este [pluglin](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/fadein/). En esta [web](http://afroleft.com/lazy-loading-responsive-images/) hay un truquillo que podría servirte, no lo he probado. Otra opción es usar un plugin distinto que esté preparado para imagenes responsivas.

Comment: Estás cargando también `lazysizes.js` ¿Por qué no usas ese que sí es responsivo?

Comment: Gracias @blonfu, de manera indirecta has dado con el clavo (y el motivo por el que a mí me funcionaba). Creo que ni el orden que pone ahí de carga de scripts es correcto, o no funcionaría lo primero (diría que `$` no está definido). O es problema del orden o de mezclar bibliotecas, porque si agrego las dos deja me funcionar bien.

Comment: ¿Podrías darnos una URL donde comprobar el problema en línea? El problema parece que es que estás mezclando jquery/lazyload con lazysites, el primero se inicia mediante tu código y el segundo con un `lazySites.init();`, pero tienes las cosas desordenadas, parece que lo has improvisado para esta pregunta, y que no es lo real. A parte, echa un vistazo a este bug por si te mejora algo: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/issues/391

Comment: Todas las imágenes poseen un ancho y largo fijo o son variables?

Comment: El ancho y el largo de las imágenes son variables ya que las imágenes son responsive y se adecuan al tamaño de la ventana.

Answer (score 0):

Hola muchas veces me ha pasado esto y no tiene que ver con el codigo para que te suceda esto una de las imagenes debe ser unos pixeles mas ancha o mas alta que las del resto de todos modos podrias ver eso antes y me comentas

Comment: Lo he estado revisando y todas parecen iguales. No creo que haya ninguna más grande que las otras ya que no se colocan por píxeles si no que son responsive, se adecuan al tamaño de la página y son todas del mismo tamaño.